# Cannot insert the value NULL into column EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a project that uses Entity Framework Code First and I'm running in the insert error "Cannot insert the value NULL into column".
Here's my code

```
[Table("Foo")]
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
}

[Table("Bar")]
public class Bar
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public int FooId{ get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

And a Insert Method that uses AutoMapper to map a Dto into Foo entity.

```
    public bool Insert(Foo obj)
    {
        Foo newFoo = this.MapFooEntity(obj);
        this._context.Foo.Add(newFoo);
        this._context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

The Foo Object AutoMapper generates don't have any problems, it generate Foo with FooId = 0 and any child (Bar) with BarId = 0.
In my view the EF should have see that BarId = 0 and attach the next indentity ID to it, but I'm getting that error. What are your thoughts guys ?

Comment: Where and which line throws exception? While adding Bar or Foo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following modification to your code:

In class `Bar`, put `[ForeignKey("FooId")]` before

```
public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
```

and put `[InverseProperty("Foo")]` before

```
public virtual List<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
```

in class `Foo`.